# How do you integrate $x^re^{-\alpha x}dx$

Tags: integration

How do you integrate the following?

$$\int_0^∞ x^re^{-\alpha x}dx$$

where $r$ and $\alpha$ are constants.

Comment: Hi, actually you function is nearly the gamma function : $ \Gamma(z) : \to \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^tdt $. It do not integrate into simple expression exepted for some values of $z$ (whole number for exemple).

Comment: just plug this into the gamma function template https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5Er+e%5E%28-ax%29+dx

Comment: See [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

Comment: $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {x^r {\rm e}^{ - \alpha x} {\rm d}x}  = \frac{1}{{\alpha ^{r + 1} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^r {\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t}  = \frac{{\varGamma (r + 1)}}{{\alpha ^{r + 1} }},
$$ provided $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha)>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(r)>-1$.

Comment: @Gary thank you! How do you get from ∫+∞0e−d=1+1∫+∞0e−d I can't see quite understand how you brought out ^-(+1)

Comment: Change the variable from $x$ to $t$ via $t=\alpha x$.

Comment: @Gary yes, got it. Thank you for your help!